# How to query XML containing duplicate element names in Solr

Tags: xml, solr, lucene

I have some XML stored in Solr that looks like this:

```
<MainData>
  <Info>
    <Info name="Bob" city="Columbus" />
    <Info name="Joe" city="Cincinnati" />
  </Info>
</MainData>
```

If I query looking for documents where MainData.Info@name:Bob and MainData.Info@city:Cincinnati, I'll get a hit for the document above. The thing is I don't want to get a hit here. I would only want to match it, if it had a line like this in it:

```
<MainData>
  <Info>
    <Info name="Bob" city="Cincinnati" />
  </Info>
</MainData>
```

Because the element names are the same "Info", I don't know how to form a Solr query that would work here.

Is this even possible?

Comment: How did you store this xml in Solr? Solr doesn't support any field type called "xml"?

Comment: I'm working with Riak 2.0, using the default schema. You can specify a content-type of XML, which tells Riak/Solr to index XML document elements and their attributes.